# Angular - how to best handle a Subject in a service and its subscriptions?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-services

I am new to `rxjs` so I am probably not using it as an experienced user would.

I am also using rxjs 5.1.0.

I have a service where I have a `BehaviorSubject` named `file$` and an observable from `file$` called `files`

```
@Injectable()
export class UploadService {
  files$: BehaviorSubject<FileToUpload[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  files: Observable<FileToUpload[]> = this.files$.asObservable();
```

This feels a bit weird to have these as member variables.

Is this correct or how better could I do this?

Then in a components `onInit` I subscribe the `files` observer:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.fileStateSubscription = this.uploadService.files.subscribe((files) => {
```

yt
On `ngDestroy` I was unsubscribing from subscription:

```
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.fileStateSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Is this correct.  I am concerned about memory leaks etc. and should I be `unsubscribing` from `files$` somehow.

I can't unsubscribe from `files$` in `ngOndestroy` or at least I would some how need to hook up the subscription again but as it is a member variable this will cause problems.

Should I be subsribing and unsubscribing every time I enter this component?

Comment: Shortly - yes, you should unsubscribing it every time and subscribe again. But you can use `.pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe$))` for all your subscription in one component, so you doesn't need to unsubscribe each subscription separately. (RxJS 6.3.*)

Comment: I am using rxjs 5.1 so there is no pipe,

Comment: I will update the question

Comment: So you should unsubscribe them separately or update to `rxjs 6.3.*`

Comment: Any chance for upgrading to rxjs 5.5?

Comment: not at the moment, why would be that different. 

How do you handle subscribing to shared observers in services?

Comment: None, I would simply prefer to leave an answer that applies to pipeable operators

Comment: so unsubscriping has an easier story in later versions?

Answer (score 3):

Point Nr 1: **It feels weird to have such member variables:**

I personally prefer the following syntax and I also saw it on larger projects:

```
export class foo {
  private foo$$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  public foo$ = this.foo$$.asObservable();
}
```

*$$ is for Subjects and other interaction Observables, $ is for pure Observables wich can be subscribed*

Point Nr 2: **Subscribe inside a Service**

Your service will not have a ngOnDestroy (*just if you only provide it for one component*) so not only because of this but please **do not subscribe** to observables **inside services**. You can do it but therefore you need to gain a deeper understanding about how services work and their lifecycle inside modules.

Point Nr 3: **Where to subscribe and how?**

Well your service now should provide one or more public readable observable, wich are already mapped/filtered/.... and ready to be - **subscribed**. Therefore you can let the service be injected into the component of your choice (*the place where you need the data*). Then in component there are two ways of subscriptions/unsibscribe managing.

**I am not sure if this one is available for rxjs 5.5 but lets give it a try:**

```
class foo {

  private subscription = new Subscription();
  constructor(private yourService: YourService) {}
  ngOnInit() {this.subscriptions.add(this.yourService.observable$.subscribe(val => 
  console.log(val)}
  ngOnDestroy() {this.subscriptions.unsibscribe()}
}
```

**The longer way but older one**

For every Observalbe create a private instance of Subscription

```
private observableSubscription;
constructor(...){}
ngOnInit() {this.observableSubscription = yourService.observable$.subscribe(...)}
ngOnDestroy() {this.observableSubscription.unsubscribe()}
```

Comment: Very nice explanations, it makes everything about subscriptions and naming a little bit clearer!

Comment: Glas I could Help out.

Answer (score 0):

You should unsubscribe from every observable you subscribe to if they do not complete by themselves in times (hot & cold observables you might want to look that up, a quick google search will give you multiple blogs). In your case hosting subjects by yourself you should definitely unsubscribe.

Having those member variables if fine you might want to use a getter for your files observable. I am not quite sure about the convention but i think the files variable should have a $ at it's end as well.

The way how you unsubscribe is correct one nice way to do so especially if you 
have multiple subscriptions in one component is to use takeUntil like  this:

```
export class YouComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
private unsubscribe$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

constructor(private yourService: YouService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.yourService.getFiles().pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)).subscribe(() => // some code)
    this.yourService.getOtherFiles().pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)).subscribe(() => // some code)
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unsubscribe.next();
    this.unsubscribe.complete();
}
}
```

This way you will unsubscribe to all observables when this.unsubscribe emits.

Ah i just read you do not have pipes:
As i remember you can just use

```
yourService.getFiles().takeUntil(this.unsubscribe).subscribe()
```

instead

Comment: Is it really necessary to call `this.unsubscribe$.complete()`? I imagine the `unsubscribe$` will be torn down anyways after the component has been destroyed.

Comment: I think it is not necessary but it is considered good practice. All examples out there i could find are calling next() + complete(). But pretty sure you are right that all objects will be garbage collected anyway after the component gets destroyed.
I guess calling complete() also avoids possible errors if there is some other subscription than just the takeUntil.

Comment: That's funny, because I haven't seen the complete() call in any examples, as far as I remember. In the end it doesn't hurt, but I would love to know what really happens under the hood when the component is destroyed.

Comment: I am obviously no expert in this field but i am almost certain that nothing special happens if the component gets destroyed. The Subject is no longer reference and will be GCed.
And as you said - it does not hurt to complete. As a general rule i'd say every well behaved subject should call complete() at the end of its live just to make sure absolutely nobody keeps a reference to it as this would prevent the Subject from being garbage collected.